# How can I get the detail of an untyped FaultException?

Tags: c#, soap

I'm calling a SOAP web service from .NET 4.5 using C#, and I can't understand how to catch the detail of an untyped `FaultException`.

If the web service experiences an error, I get a message like this one:

```xml
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>GSX.SYS.003</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Multiple error messages exist. Please check the detail section.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <operationId>HqrCoRMbtKczWFH2WMuFJGe</operationId>
            <errors>
               <error>
                  <code>ENT.UPL.005</code>
                  <message>User ID is required for authentication.</message>
               </error>
               <error>
                  <code>ENT.UPL.005</code>
                  <message>Password is required for authentication.</message>
               </error>
               <error>
                  <code>ENT.UPL.005</code>
                  <message>Sold-To is required for authentication.</message>
               </error>
            </errors>
         </detail>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

To catch the error, I wrap the call in a try/catch block and catch the `FaultException`:

```cs
try
{
    // Do something.
}
catch (FaultException faultException)
{
    var messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
    // ???
    throw;
}
```

The problem lies in the `// ???` line: how can I access the detail of the `FaultException`, given that I can't use `messageFault.GetDetail<T>()` because the detail is untyped?

For the code and the reason I don't have a problem, I get them with `messageFault.Code.Name` and `messageFault.Reason.Translations.Single().Text`.

What I've been able to concoct is this:

```cs
var stringWriter = new StringWriter();
var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
var messageFault = faultException.CreateMessageFault();
messageFault.WriteTo(xmlTextWriter, EnvelopeVersion.Soap12);
var stringValue = Convert.ToString(stringWriter);
var nameTable = new NameTable();
var xmlNamespaceManager = new XmlNamespaceManager(nameTable);
xmlNamespaceManager.AddNamespace("soap", "http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope");
var xmlDocument = XDocument.Parse(stringValue);
var operationId =
    xmlDocument
    .XPathSelectElement("/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/operationId", xmlNamespaceManager)
    .Value;
var errors =
    xmlDocument
    .XPathSelectElements("/soap:Fault/soap:Detail/errors/error", xmlNamespaceManager)
    .Select(element => new
        {
            Code = element.XPathSelectElement("code").Value,
            Message = element.XPathSelectElement("message").Value
        })
    .ToArray();
```

But null reference and encoding issues aside, it's a monster.

There *must* be a saner way to get the details.

Comment: Have you found a saner way so far? I'm currently having the EXACT same issue (Soap-Fault, detail field, array not parsed) and wonder if you found a solution where you dont need to parse yourself. What I think so far is that the generated code from the WSDL is faulty and doesn't recognize the array in the soap-fault detail field.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the detail as an XML type, eg. [XElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) or [XmlElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlelement.aspx) and process it using XPath, Linq to XML or just treat it as string.

In a similar situation I use the following code to get at the contents of an admittedly simple details element:

```
var detail = fault.GetDetail<XElement>();
return detail.Value;
```

Comment: Hello, I tested your solution and it does not yield a correct result: only the first item of the exception is returned (in my example, `<operationId />`). Trying to use `XElement[]`, `IEnumerable<XElement>` or something similar and exception throws with the message `Expecting element 'ArrayOfXElement' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Xml.Linq'.. Encountered 'Element'  with name 'operationId', namespace ''.`.

Comment: I can also confirm that unfortunately this only deserialises the first node.

Comment: @LeeOades of course it doesn't, that's the call to read a single element. This works if Detail returns a simple message - which is also mentioned in the answer.  `GetDetail` simply deserializes the contents of the `Detail` element into whatever type you specify. The point is that WCF already provides access to the error detail, there's no need to try and read the entire response.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the following response:

```xml
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:InternalServiceFault</faultcode>
         <faultstring>One or more errors have occurred.</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
               <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
               <InnerException>
                  <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
                  <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
                  <Message>...</Message>
                  <StackTrace>...</StackTrace>
                  <Type>System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException</Type>
               </InnerException>
               <Message>One or more errors have occurred.</Message>
               <StackTrace>...</StackTrace>
               <Type>System.AggregateException</Type>
            </ExceptionDetail>
         </detail>
      </s:Fault>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

You can access the inner exception with this code:

```cs
var messageFault = ex.CreateMessageFault();
var detail = messageFault.GetDetail<ExceptionDetail>();
var innerException = detail.InnerException;
```

In your case the body of detail should be serializable to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code that emulate how SoapException could provide SoapException.Detail.OuterXml:

```
private string GetDetailOuterXml(MessageFault mf)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.Append("<detail>");
    using var r = mf.GetReaderAtDetailContents();
    while (!r.EOF)
        sb.Append(r.ReadOuterXml());
    sb.Append("</detail>");
    return sb.ToString();
}
```